# p4 Get changelist number from a trigger

Tags: python, perforce

Im trying to write a p4 trigger on change-submit.
Trigger will do some basic validation, then allows /blocks the submit.
How to get the change number from inside the trigger so that I could use it for some validations.?

Answer (score 3):

You would pass the changelist as an argument to your trigger script, like so:

```
Triggers:
    trig1 change-submit //depot/dir/... "/usr/bin/s1.pl %changelist%"
```

From:

[Perforce 2012.1: Command Reference - p4 triggers](https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r12.1/manuals/cmdref/triggers.html)